# Я могу разместить информацию на данном сайте о своей разработке и в какой форме (например, ссылкой на сайт разработчика)?

Tags: поддержка, реклама

Я могу разместить информацию на данном сайте о своей разработке и в какой форме (например, ссылкой на сайт разработчика)?

Comment: Такую информацию можно разместить разве что в своём профиле.  Вопросы и ответы с _саморекламой_ и ссылками на свой сайт размещать нельзя, они будут отфильтрованы как спам, см. [Как не быть спамером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).  Однако можно осуществлять [поддержку своего продукта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: Задайте вопрос о какой-нибудь конкретной проблеме в вашей разработке (можете даже выдумать-смоделировать ошибку)

Answer (score 4):

В профиле участника есть поле для ссылки на личный сайт. Больше никак.